# Utility off using an additional file descriptor?

Tags: linux

I know you can create a file descriptor and redirect output to it.

But you can do the same thing without the file descriptor.

When you would have to use an additional file descriptor.

Comment: Can you give more details please?

Comment: using a new file description, we can redirect I/O like this:        exec 3 > dump.log
echo a >&3 
exec 3>&-                                                                
 
But you can do the same thing without the file descriptor:         echo a > dump.log

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect without using a file descriptor, i.e:

```
echo haha > dump.log
```

It's equivalent to

```
echo haha 1>dump.log
```

1 is the file descriptor for standard output.

2 is the file descriptor for standard error, so if you want to redirect error messages coming from a command, you can use this file descriptor

```
ech lol 2>dump.log
```

These are the cases where you would need file descriptors.

For example, if you are writing a script, which contains naturally a lot of commands, you can use redirection for many purposes:

- Log the commands and their execution in a log file to follow the workflow of the script
- log the error messages in a log file to know if there were any error messages
- there are some error messages, or some output that you want to ignore, and you can 'incinerate' it by redirecting it to `/dev/null`